# Integrate type name in static_assert output?

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, custom-errors, static-assert

I like to give helpful errors / messages, and I also want to do so for my `static_assert`s. The problem is, that they depend on template parameters. Normally, those parameters will get displayed on way or an other due to the error raised, but they are either obscure or not grouped so they make sense. Example:

```
template<class T>
struct fake_dependency{
  static bool const value = false;
};

template<class T, class Tag>
struct Foo{
  Foo(){}

  template<class OtherTag>
  Foo(Foo<T, OtherTag> const&){
    static_assert(fake_dependency<T>::value, "Cannot create Foo<T,Tag> from Foo<T,OtherTag>.");
  }
};

int main(){
    Foo<int, struct TagA> fA;
    Foo<int, struct TagB> fB(fA);
}
```

Output on MSVC:

```
src\main.cpp(74): error C2338: Cannot create Foo<T,Tag> from Foo<T,OtherTag>.
          src\main.cpp(84) : see reference to function template instantiation 'Foo<T,Tag>::Foo<main::TagA>(const Foo<T,main::TagA> &)' being compiled
          with
          [
              T=int,
              Tag=main::TagB
          ]
```

One tag is mentioned in the function template itself, the other below with the class template. Not so nice. Lets see what [GCC outputs](http://ideone.com/ElIm1):

```
prog.cpp: In constructor 'Foo<T, Tag>::Foo(const Foo<T, OtherTag>&) [with OtherTag = main()::TagA, T = int, Tag = main()::TagB]':
prog.cpp:18:32:   instantiated from here
prog.cpp:12:5: error: static assertion failed: "Cannot create Foo<T,Tag> from Foo<T,OtherTag>."
```

Much better, but still not really where the `static_assert` is. And now imagine some more parameters, or more templates, or both. *shivers*

One way to work around that is to use an intermediate struct, which takes both Tags as template parameters:

```
template<class Tag, class OtherTag>
struct static_Foo_assert{
    static_assert(fake_dependency<Tag>::value, "Cannot create Foo<T,Tag> from Foo<T,OtherTag>.");
};

template<class T, class Tag>
struct Foo{
  Foo(){}

  template<class OtherTag>
  Foo(Foo<T, OtherTag> const&){
      static_Foo_assert<Tag, OtherTag> x;
  }
};
```

Now lets see the output again:

```
src\main.cpp(70): error C2338: Cannot create Foo<T,Tag> from Foo<T,OtherTag>.
          src\main.cpp(79) : see reference to class template instantiation 'static_Foo_assert<Tag,OtherTag>' being compiled
          with
          [
              Tag=main::TagB,
              OtherTag=main::TagA
          ]
```

Much better! Here's what [GCC says](http://ideone.com/pHLAq):

```
prog.cpp: In instantiation of 'static_Foo_assert<main()::TagB, main()::TagA>':
prog.cpp:17:40:   instantiated from 'Foo<T, Tag>::Foo(const Foo<T, OtherTag>&) [with OtherTag = main()::TagA, T = int, Tag = main()::TagB]'
prog.cpp:23:32:   instantiated from here
prog.cpp:8:5: error: static assertion failed: "Cannot create Foo<T,Tag> from Foo<T,OtherTag>."
```

Looks not bad. The problem: I need to create such a struct for every template, since the error message in `static_assert` needs to be a string literal...

Now, for my question: Can we somehow include the type names directly into the `static_assert`? Like

```
static_assert(..., "Cannot create Foo<" T "," Tag "> from Foo<" T "," OtherTag ">.");
```

Example output:

> Cannot create `Foo<int,main::TagA>` from `Foo<int,main::TagB>`.

Or, if that isn't achievable, can we somehow make the error message an extra template parameter, as to make it passable?

Comment: I would like to see the compilers become better here. It must be possible to show the condition that failed. It could say `note: in static_assert check for fake_dependency<T>::value [with T = ...]` (in the brackets, it enumerates all template parameters used in the expression). Let's hope!

Comment: @Johannes: I think that could be done with `constexpr` expression templates, don't you think? Like you can already disassembly runtime expressions / conditions like the Check unit-testing framework does.

Comment: Too bad concepts didn't make into C++0x that would greatly reduce the need as it stands `typeid` or `dyanamic_cast` are the only way to determine type and both require an instance which you don't have with a template arg.

Comment: @AJ: Actually, the `typeid` operator is perfectly valid on types only: `typeid(int)` for example. But the problem is, that `static_assert` wants a literal string. :(

Comment: Do you know all your types in advance?  If so you can create an error template with specializations for each type.

Comment: @Dean: I can possibly handcraft `invalid_use_of_<>` templates, for every message I want, like [abused here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8763497/how-to-drive-c-c-or-java-compiler-to-compute-123-1000/8763548#8763548), but I specifically asked for `static_assert`. :/

Comment: My answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13837668/display-integer-at-compile-time-in-static-assert/48713832#48713832

Answer (score 15):

### My Hack

#### Code:

```
template <typename Assertion>
struct AssertValue : AssertionChecker<Assertion::value, Assertion>
{
    static_assert(AssertionValue, "Assertion failed <see below for more information>");
    static bool const value = Assertion::value;
};
```

It allows for you to check any `::value` assertion and dump the types if it failed.

#### Usage:

```
// Bad indentation used to show parts
static_assert(
    AssertValue<
        std::my_check<
            T0, decltype(*somethingComplicated), T7::value_type
        >
    >, 
    "something horrible happened"
);
```

where `std::my_check<...>::value` is the boolean result of the check

#### Example

For a full [SSCCE](http://sscce.org) example see: [IDEOne Example](http://ideone.com/AcwsCA)

The Example's error message:

```
prog.cpp: In instantiation of 'AssertValue<std::is_base_of<IMyInterface, MyBadType> >':
prog.cpp:37:69:   instantiated from 'void MyFunction(IteratorType, IteratorType) [with IteratorType = __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<MyBadType*, std::vector<MyBadType> >]'
prog.cpp:60:38:   instantiated from here
prog.cpp:9:5: error: static assertion failed: "Assertion failed <see below for more information>"
prog.cpp: In function 'void MyFunction(IteratorType, IteratorType) [with IteratorType = __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<MyBadType*, std::vector<MyBadType> >]':
prog.cpp:60:38:   instantiated from here
prog.cpp:39:5: error: static assertion failed: "iterator passed does not reference IMyInterface items"
```

#### Explanation

If the assertion fails, it will print the template arguments of AssertValue and therefore print the full template expansion of your check. For example, if you were checking a `std::is_base_of` it will print the full type of the check, e.g.: `std::is_base_of<IMyInterface, MyBadType>`. Then you know exactly what types were used in the failed assertion.

The only problem is that this only works on templates that put their result in `::value`. However `type_traits` mostly uses this and is the goto standard.

Comment: Not as nice as I'd like it, but not bad either. I think you mean `<see above ...` though, judging from GCC and MSVC errors.

Comment: @Xeo I did see below because I think MSVC puts the failed assert first before dumping out the types... GCC does the opposite

Comment: Ideone example not present anymore... http://ideone.com/AcwsCA  And response code is not complete, AssertionChecker missing

Comment: Where is `AssertionValue` defined?

Comment: Shouldn't use bool as type as that might be a valid type.

Answer (score 3):

If your compiler provides the `__FUNCTION__` macro, you can have a really simple substitution using it and literal concatenation.  However, gcc's and clang's implementation is not done as a macro, so this solution will not work for them.

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <type_traits>

template <class T>
class must_be_pod
{
    static void test() { static_assert (std::is_pod<T>::value, __FUNCTION__ ": not a POD"); }
public:
    must_be_pod() { test(); }
};

class not_a_pod
{
public:
    not_a_pod() {}
    virtual ~not_a_pod() {}
};

int main()
{
    must_be_pod<not_a_pod> should_fail; // and it does
    return 0;
}
```

This produces the following output when compiled by VS2015:

```
static_assert_test.cpp(10): error C2338: must_be_pod<class not_a_pod>::test: not a POD
```

Comment: This won't work with GCC or Clang, as they don't have \_\_FUNCTION__ as a macro.

Comment: Also, although Embarcadero C++ has the `__FUNCTION__` macro, it won't let you (10.1) use it as the message in a `static_assert`.

Comment: Actually, according to https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Function-Names.html gcc does indeed support `__FUNCTION__` as well as `__PRETTY_FUNCTION__`.

Comment: But they're not macros, `__FUNCTION___` is a macro in MSVC — it gets replaced with a string literal at compile time which is what makes this work.

Answer (score 2):

It's possible to get a string literal passed in as a template non-type parameter, with a little bit of [hoop-jumping](http://ideone.com/iU43U). But since the second argument to `static_assert` is constrained to be a string literal rather than, say, an address constant expression, this unfortunately is not much use.

Sadly I suspect your best bet is to lobby the committee or the compiler writers to extend the facility.

Answer (score -1):

I see this has been answered a while ago, but the full answer was lost, and I found a very simply way to achieve the desired result.

```
template <typename T, bool value>
static typename std::enable_if<value, void>::type FunctionWithReadableErrorMessage()
{
}


int  main()
{
    FunctionWithReadableErrorMessage<int, false>();
    return 0;
}
```

This function will compile and have no effect if value=true, otherwise we get this error message:

> main.cpp: In function 'int main()': main.cpp:16:50: error: no matching
>   function for call to 'FunctionWithReadableErrorMessage()'
>        FunctionWithReadableErrorMessage();
>                                                     ^

If we wanna be a bit more general we can put it in a macro