# Warnings that will consistently get triggered across different compilers?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, gcc, compiler-warnings, clang

After writing an answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8763497/how-to-drive-c-c-or-java-compiler-to-compute-123-1000) which displays the solution at compile time with an error, I wondered if it was possible to get a warning instead and finish compilation (as is actually specified in the question).

While diagnostics in general are compiler-dependant, it's pretty obvious for some code that an error will get triggered (such as accessing a non-existent member or trying to instantiate an object of incomplete type).

The same can't be said for warnings though, since these tend to differ a great deal between compilers. Even though it's reasonable to assume that warnings triggered with GCC will also get triggered with Clang, the same can not be said for Visual C++.

Question:
**Which warnings, if any, will consistently get triggered on all three mentioned compilers?**

`/W3` on VC++ and `-Wall` on GCC & Clang may be assumed.

---

Note that this is not only useful for that question, but may be useful for triggering a warning for user-defined messages aswell.

Comment: Why do you use `/W3` on MSVC while using `-Wall` on GCC/Clang? MSVC supports `/W4` and `/Wall` as additional warning levels.

Comment: @Cody: I think of them as the "default" setup for the compilers. I don't want to have to change the warning level to get the warning displayed. `/W3` is the actual default in Visual Studio and `-Wall` can be seen as a default too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work on MSVC, GCC, and Clang:

```
#pragma message("hello world")
```

Not very useful, but still works.

These picked up warnings too:

- unused variable
- unused label
- large values e.g. (1 << 128)

Comment: Can't display any template stuff with that. :( And that doesn't really count as a warning now, does it?

Comment: @Xeo Yeah, although it is guaranteed to work - warnings not so much.