# Include type or function name inside static_assert error

Tags: c++, c++11

There are many cases where template functions and types need a static-assertion to restrict the acceptable types of specializations or other conditions. Then a meaningful compiler error message is desired. If you don't want to write a string literal one one-by-one for each case, you create some macros for the error messages or for the complete assertions, but
**how to implicitly include the name of the type / function to the error message?**

In the following example *FUNCNAME* is a fictional keyword which should make the magic happen:

```
#include <type_traits>

#define ASSERT_INTEGRAL(T) static_assert(std::is_integral<T>::value, \
FUNCNAME ## " would be happy with specializations for integral types");

template <typename T>
class A
{
  public:

    A()
    {
        ASSERT_INTEGRAL(T)
    }
};
```

For template types, if you perform the static assertion inside the constructor, maybe the name of the function just enough. For such cases there is the C99 standard macro `__func__`, but as it turns out static_assert doesn't accept it as a string literal.

So what is the solution?

Comment: The compiler should do its best to provide the context of the assertion failure, including the types involved. There is no portable/standard way of doing this that I know of.

Comment: Then suggest some compiler specific solution and I will build an #ifdef structured block.

Comment: I'm not aware of a compiler specific solution either. Remember the error message triggered by a fialing `static_assert` will already contain this information!

Comment: For example, gcc will report something like: `In instantiation of 'A<T>::A() [with T = std::basic_string<char>]':` - which should give you everything you need. If your compiler doesn't - maybe it's time for an upgrade?

Comment: Also - this may provide some pointers: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6415186/integrate-type-name-in-static-assert-output